# how can i insert a condition into a Razor html file in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i tried this

```
@{
    if(item.typeElement=="Multi")
       <tr bgcolor="#FFCCCC">
    else
    <tr>
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to work 
how can i do it ?

Comment: Be cautious about comparing strings in this manner.  [MSDN would recommends`item.typeElement.Equals("multi", StringComparison.OrdinalIngoreCase)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

While David's answer looks correct (not sure where your error is coming from), you may tighten things up using the ternary operator:

```
<tr @(item.typeElement=="Multi" ? " bgcolor='#FFCCCC'" : "")>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `<tr bgcolor="#FFCCCC">` and `<tr>` aren't valid C# code.  They're HTML.

Don't wrap the whole thing in a code block, just use the inline Razor syntax:

```
@if (item.typeElement=="Multi")
{
    <tr bgcolor="#FFCCCC">
}
else
{
    <tr>
}
```

Comment: @MrIlias: Define "didn't work".  What's the error?  How is it failing?  Please try to understand that I can't see your screen from here.

Comment: Parser Error Message: The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Comment: Line 40:     </tr>
Line 41: 
Line 42: @foreach (var item in Model) {
Line 43:     if (item.typeElement=="Multi")
Line 44:     {

Comment: @MrIlias: There is no `foreach` in the code you've shown.  I make no guarantees that *other code you've written which you haven't shown here* is without error.  This isn't a magic wand, it's just an answer to only the question you asked.

Comment: The Intellisense for razor will most likely freakout about this and say tags aren't closed etc..